# Default constraint with synonym or UDF from other database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, synonym

Is it possible to add default constraint with synonym or UDF from other database?

```
Create table TestTable (
ID int identity(1,1), 
SData varchar(100), 
UserName varchar(100) default [OtherDatabaseName].dbo.fn_Test('value'))
```

Below is the error message, while I am trying to add default constraint

> The name "OtherDatabaseName" is not permitted in this context. Valid
>   expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some
>   contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

We can add UDF from same database but I want add UDF from other database. Because it is used in multiple databases on same server.

And I do not want to create that UDF in all database and prevent duplicate code.

Please let me know if there is any other/better way. Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking this because it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it does not work with function from different database?

Comment: What did the error message say?

Comment: Added error message in question.

Comment: I've been looking for an official reference where it sais you can or cannot do it, but they don't mention this case. But apparantly SQL Server doesn't support it, hence the error message. Have you tried with a synonym as well?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with synonym but getting "Synonyms are invalid in a schemabound object or a constraint expression."

Answer (score 1):

> Please let me know if there is any other/better way.

One other way would be to use a trigger instead of a default.